# Can't open terminal in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I have installed ubuntu on the virtual box, and I can't open the terminal in my virtual box. I have tried enabling the terminal using the prompt that is opened by ctrl+alt+f4 keys, but I couldn't do anything because "vboxuser is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported".

What should I do to be able to open the terminal?

The machine is ubuntu-22.04.1 dekstop.

Comment: You've not mentioned what Ubuntu product & what release you installed, but if you're logging into a normal desktop system, `sudoers` is not involved when opening a user terminal, so providing more details maybe required. What username did you install/setup with?  as it looks like *vboxuser* which would be automatically added to a Ubuntu Desktop install if the setup user account (*but you didn't provide product/release details so we're only guessing currently*).

Comment: @guiverc, I have created a virtual machine with the newer ubuntu version, and I still have the same problem

Comment: How are you trying to open a terminal? Are you clicking on the terminal app's icon? Are you using Ctrl+Shift+T? Something else? How exactly did you try "enabling the terminal using the prompt that is opened by ctrl+alt+f4 keys"? What did you do?

Comment: Sorry,  I am having the same problem.